# Use differents types of titles in one Fancybox gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I make a topic, today, because I've a problem with the plug-in Fancybox 2.0 (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

In fact, I want to set different types of title, according the media that is currently in the fancybox. If there is an iFrame in my Fancybox, the title must be "outside". Else, if it's other media, the title must be "over".

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({openEffect: 'elastic',closeEffect: 'elastic',beforeShow: function() {
        share_buttons_fancybox = '<div class="center" style="margin-top:10px;"><div class="bouton_social"><div class="fb-like" data-href="' + $(this.element).attr('href') + '" data-width="90" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div></div><div class="bouton_social"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" data-url="' + $(this.element).attr('href') + '" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="playeronetv" data-lang="fr">Tweeter</a></div><div class="bouton_social"><div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" addthis:url="' + $(this.element).attr('href') + '"><a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-52248d25116616ca"></script></div></div>';
        if (this.title) {
            this.title += share_buttons_fancybox;
        } else {
            this.title = share_buttons_fancybox;
        }
    },afterShow: function() {
        twttr.widgets.load();
        FB.XFBML.parse();
        addthis.toolbox();
        addthis.toolbox(".addthis_toolbox");
        addthis.counter(".addthis_counter");
    },helpers: {thumbs: {width: 80,height: 45},title: {type: 'over'}},padding: 0})
```

Any ideas ? iFrame and others medias must be in the same Fancybox galery. :)

Thanks by advance, and sorry for my english (I'm French) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `title` position to `over` for all elements using the `helpers` option and set the `title` position to `outside` for *iframe* elements only using the jQuery's `$.extend()` method inside the `afterLoad` callback this way :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    openEffect: 'elastic',
    closeEffect: 'elastic',
    helpers: {
        thumbs: {
            width: 80,
            height: 45
        },
        title: {
            type: 'over' // all media
        }
    },
    afterLoad: function () {
        if (this.type == "iframe") {
            $.extend(this, {
                helpers: {
                    title: {
                        type: 'outside' // iframe only
                    },
                    overlay: {
                        locked: false // needed to fix a bug while closing (can be true or false)
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Notice** that I set the `overlay` `locked` option inside the `$.extend()` method to workaround a bug while closing fancybox :

```
overlay: {
    locked: false 
}
```

without this, the overlay won't close (requires a second `click` to close though)

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zPB8s/)**