# Fancybox move title only for YouTube video

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have one gallery with two types of contents: images and YouTube videos

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    padding : 0,
    beforeShow: function () {
        /* Disable right click */
        $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                return false; 
        });
        if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';

            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='+this.href+'&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=21&amp;appId=443532569031197" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';

        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        //show title over image
        $(".fancybox-title").wrapInner('<div />').show();

        //title show on hover effect
        $(".fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
            $(".fancybox-title").show();
        }, function() {
            $(".fancybox-title").hide();
        });

        //adding custom text append picture
        var text = $(this.element).attr('data-own');
        if(text)
            this.inner.append( '<p>' + text +'<p>' );
    },
    helpers : {
        //custom background
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)'
            }
        },
        title: {
            type: 'over'
        }
    }
});
```

Try on http://jsfiddle.net/tonda13/c5ePL/

I need move title to 'outside' or completly hide only for YouTube videos. Do you have some advice?

Comment: Since videos open inside an iframe, you can apply this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/19944217/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use differents types of titles in one Fancybox gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904338/use-differents-types-of-titles-in-one-fancybox-gallery)